# azure AD Security groups of a User

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory

I am trying to get all of security groups of Authenticated user as in the example [Github example](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-groupclaims/blob/master/WebApp-GroupClaims-DotNet/Utils/ClaimHelper.cs), and it works for many people, but for one man it does not work. He has 403 error (forbidden) when the app requests his groups (lines 43-49). I am a beginner with the azure ad, and what can be a reason of this situation? All of other people a prepared correctly as in this example. Thanx a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is connected with the agreements. Some users had logged in before we added new requirement and the login page (I do not know why) did not ask the new accept. So the graph api just blocked our requests of these user's security groups.

Answer (score 0):

I would first check the User profile in Azure AD and make sure everything looks good there. Then I would ask the user to send a Fiddler trace so you can see what data is being sent and received.